# Office 365 email(s) no longer available through POP3

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, smtp, pop3

I am hoping this question relates to some kind of outage that will be resolved.
I am using this dialog to retreive messages from outlook 365.

I have been through every setting I can find, and from what I can tell POP3 is enabled for the acount, and should work just fine.

It's just in the last couple of days that it started, and I have changed no settings. Is there a policy change or something in office 365 that has changed recently.

I am certain that the password is correct because the STMP leg works fine, and outbound email can get out. It's just inbound that's not working.

[image]

The SMTP leg works just fine, and I can still send messages.

[image]

Modern authentication is not ticked in the Org Section of the 365 Admin Portal.

Comment: It is possible that your company has disabled username/password access and requires oAuth authentication instead.

Comment: It's not the POP access itself, which is still working for me, but sometimes the access gets screwed if there's ever any hiccup at the server. The symptom for me is always 'password was rejected, please re-enter'. Touching this at all screws up access. Attempting to re-enter the password never works. I've recently figured out a method to persuade it to reset - I set all accounts to 'offline', quit the mail app, relaunch & set back to 'online'. If that doesn't work, I try again with a reboot rather than just re-launch. If ***that*** doesn't work, I have to change the password from the web page.

Comment: It started working again, so there was some kind of outage.